# Can't use @Embedded for a list of Objects Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

This is the main Document type I have

```
@Entity("users")
public class UserModel {
   @Id
   private ObjectId id;
   private String userID;
   private String prefix;
   @Embedded
   private List<TodoList> todoLists;
   @Embedded
   private List<Reminder> reminders;
// Getters, setters, constructor
```

This is the TodoList class instead:

```
@Embedded
public class TodoList {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String name;
    private List<String> todos;
    private List<String> completed;
```

I get this error for the @Embedded annotation of the List:

```
UserModel.java:18: error: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
   @Embedded
```

I can't really understand what I'm doing wrong...

(I'm using Morphia 2.0.1 and even putting a simple TodoList class instead of a list of those classes  throws that error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out that @Embedded is not usable on fields, but just on classes. So I just had to simply remove it from the UserModel and keep it in the TodoList class.